# JBOSS cluster licence free or opensource

Tags: jboss, redhat

i want to make new environment in j boss.boss. J boss is free.but i would to like to know about j boss cluster,is it free or we have to purchase?

Answer (score 0):

All are free to use.

Except for EAP, which you need a licence for production. You can use it for development for free though.